# Concat Max Value to an int32 using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new in using Linq and I'm having a problem on how to Concat a max value in my database to be used as unique attribute using linq. I have found a solution but it is written in SQL query

`(select ISNULL(MAX(PersonID + 1), 100000) as nn from Persons)`

and tried it and the max personId is 80 so the output becomes `100081` Thanks

EDIT: so i stand corrected, it only acts as Case, sorry guys i feel so dumb :(

Comment: If the max `personId` is `80`, from this query it will return `81`. Also I don't understand `100000` part, why you would set to `100000` if your `id` does not exist in that table?

Comment: @SeM no sir it will return `100081` because of the `100000` that is being concat

Comment: Where do you see `Concat` here? It will check if `PersonId` is null then it will `SELECT 100000` if it is not - `MAX(PersonID + 1)`.

Comment: could you run this command and check output `(select ISNULL(MAX(PersonID + 1), 999999999) as nn from Persons)`

Comment: @Ehsan.Saradar so i stand corrected, it only acts as Case, sorry guys i feel so dumb :(

Comment: @SeM so i stand corrected, it only acts as Case, sorry guys i feel so dumb :( so this statement is checking if personid is not null

Comment: That sql query in LINQ (and by that I assume linq2sql and EF) would be something like this: `var maxId = context.Persons.Max(p => (int?)p.PersonID) + 1 ?? 100000;` and instead of `int?` your type.

Comment: @SeM is it also the same with , `PersonId != null : p.personId + 1 ? 100000` ??

Comment: @EnriqueGil It is the same with: `var maxId = context.Persons.Max(p => (int?)p.PersonID); maxId = maxId != null ? maxId+1 : 100000;`

Comment: @EnriqueGil ok, you're welcome!